# Как во Vue переопределять стили Bootstrap?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap

Если применять этот код

```html
<style lang="scss">
  .custom-btn {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

, то стили не применяются, если я прописываю этот класс в кнопке в template. Срабатывает только с !important, но это не вариант. Есть вариант как это переопределять?

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать [атрибут `scoped`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/ru/guide/scoped-css.html) у тега - это включит автодобавление data-атрибута со случайным значением, и оно несколько повысит специфичность селекторов (которую конечно надо повышать и самому, по ситуации) _//оффтоп: вообще, я не рекомендую стили в компонентах (чисто по опыту, отдельный файл стилей в поддержке значительно проще когда приложение разрастается)_

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
<style lang="scss">
  ::v-deep .custom-btn {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.use the style attribute to add CSS inline on your divs

eg: ...

2.create your own style sheet and reference it after the existing stylesheet

then your style sheet should take precedence.

3.add a  element in the  of your HTML with the CSS you need,

this will take precedence over an external style sheet.

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, ответ на русский язык, а на источник английского текста (если он есть) дайте ссылку.